# How to balance image position in a div with borders?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have put an image in a div. Border top, right, left of the div are balanced and have the same distance from the image edges. But the border bottom intersects the border of the div and as you see, there is no space left between the image bottom edge and the div border. How should I fix it?
[image]
Here is my css code

```
.thumbnail{
    height: 230px; 
    width: 141px; 
    max-height: 198px; 
    max-width: 141px;
    float: left; 
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.thumbnail img {
    height: 100px; 
    width: 141px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And here is the HTML

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img style="opacity: 1;" src="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/MV5BMTQ2NjA5MTA3NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDk1MDExMzE-203x300.jpg" class="attachment-170x212 wp-post-image" alt="MV5BMTQ2NjA5MTA3NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDk1MDExMzE" height="212" width="143">
</div>
```

Comment: you should have put your HTML here as well.

Comment: Did you set bottom: x px; anywhere? x is the distance to the bottom

Comment: @Marcel I think there should be a way that bottom image edge would be balanced like the TOP, LEFT, and RIGHT.

Comment: @Varun I updated and put my HTML code as well.

Comment: @FreeMind Where's the border style? You didn't include it to your sample codes.

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. The border is added by the FireFox automatically, `border: 1px solid #DDD`

Comment: @FreeMind I think it's working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/581pwxy5/1/

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. Is there anyway to make the img fit div vertically?

Comment: @FreeMind So, you want the image to fit with its parent .thumbnail?

Comment: @FreeMind I will post my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `width` and `height` of the **image** to `100%`.

**Here's the [JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/581pwxy5/3/).**

**E.g.**

```
.thumbnail img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Remove** the `height="212" width="143"` in the image and `overflow: hidden;` in the `.thumbnail img`.

```
<img src="http://static.hdw.eweb4.com/media/wallpapers_dl/1/106/1058184-beautiful-landscapes.jpg" alt="MV5BMTQ2NjA5MTA3NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDk1MDExMzE" />
```

Always end an `img` tag with `/>`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

you just need to set the properties in `.thumbnail img`

the key property is `padding`

see snippet below:

```css
.thumbnail img {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 5%; /* whatever you like here */
  border: 1px solid red /* whatever you like here */
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img style="opacity: 1;" src="http://placehold.it/212x143" class="attachment-170x212 wp-post-image" alt="MV5BMTQ2NjA5MTA3NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDk1MDExMzE">
</div>
```

**EDIT:**  OP's Comment

> No, it does not work. Indeed, it gives some padding but for images
>   with more height, the problem still appears

So here you have a 3 different `img`s with 3 different `height`s and still same result as my first snippet.

```css
/*demo purposes */
.thumbnail {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1%
}
/* end demo purposes */

.thumbnail img {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 5%;  /* whatever you like here */
  border: 1px solid red  /* whatever you like here */
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img style="opacity: 1;" src="http://placehold.it/175x200" class="attachment-170x212 wp-post-image" alt="MV5BMTQ2NjA5MTA3NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDk1MDExMzE">
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img style="opacity: 1;" src="http://placehold.it/175x450" class="attachment-170x212 wp-post-image" alt="MV5BMTQ2NjA5MTA3NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDk1MDExMzE">
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img style="opacity: 1;" src="http://placehold.it/175x750" class="attachment-170x212 wp-post-image" alt="MV5BMTQ2NjA5MTA3NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDk1MDExMzE">
</div>
```

Comment: No, it does not work. Indeed, it gives some padding but for images with more height, the problem still appears.